# Can I do sorting for an declared object? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have declared a worksheet as object, and try do sorting in the worksheet, but encountered error "Sort method of Range class failed". I guess an object cannot be used with Sort function?
But I must declare the worksheet as object, otherwise encounter another error for the "Set Spreadsheet1 = newwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")"...anyway to fix it?

```
Public newwb As Object
Public Spreadsheet1 As Object

Set newwb = CreateObject("excel.Application")
Set newwb = newwb.Workbooks.Add
Set Spreadsheet1 = newwb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Spreadsheet1.Activate

With Spreadsheet1
    .Range("A1:D100").Select
    .Range("A1:D100").Sort Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: You have to pass *some* arguments to the `Sort` method to tell it how to sort.

Comment: Thanks, it works after I have added some argument to do the sort, like Key1:=Spreadsheet1.Range("A1:D100")

Comment: I apologise - I didn't think adding the keys would help, but I see that it does.  (I wonder why Excel itself won't allow it?)